# Android : How to set ringing mode to silent in Lollipop

Tags: android, audio, android-5.0-lollipop

Prior Lollipop i was using below code to Mute Ringing Tone

```
// Mute Ringtone

AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

It is not working anyomore on devices runnning on lollipop. It although sets the **priority mode** but do not silence at all. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Downvoters pls care to write some comment before downvoting. It really is ok if you do not know the answer.

Comment: Have you got an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

```
setRingerMode()
```

Sets the ringer mode.

Silent mode will mute the volume and will not vibrate. Vibrate mode will mute the volume and vibrate. Normal mode will be audible and may vibrate according to user settings.

This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume policy as indicated by "isVolumeFixed()".

as mentioned in :-
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode(int)

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isVolumeFixed()

But this function works on my nexus 4 running android 5.0. However, call ringtone does not get silent immediately but after completion of playing once cycle of tone in which mute call ringtone button is pressed and this code is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not help. I need to set the Ringtone mode to None in Lollipop.